# How to edit a field--field-xxx.tpl file when the content is rendered with Display Suite?

Tags: theming, display-suite

I want to show up to 3 images in my teasers. For that I override the `field--field-image.tpl` file in my theme directory and it works perfectly.

```
<?php

if ($element['#view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
    $items = array(array_slice($items, 0,3));
    }

    print "<div class=\"gallery-thumbs\">".render($items)."</div>";
?>
```

I would like to use a Display Suite layout instead for the teaser, but the `field--field-image.tpl` has no effect anymore. Where should I put this code to achieve the same effect (up to 3 thumbnails) using a Display Suite layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a little bit ashamed, but if the issue occurs to someone else, it is not even necessary to write code. There is a dedicated field in the manage display interface.

[image]